# Convert string to all uppercase leters with std::transform

Tags: c++, stl

I'm using transform algorithm and std::toupper to achieve this, but can this be done in one line, like this ?

```
transform(s.begin(), s.end(), ostream_iterator<string>(cout, "\n"),std::toupper);
```

I get error on this, so do I have to make a unary function for this and call it with transform or I can use some adaptors ?

Comment: It is important to post the actual error that you are getting. In particular in a comment to the accepted answer you have added that error, and that in turn says that the problem is with overload resolution. At that point, with all the information, people can come up with a clear explanation of what the problem is and different ways to solve it, rather than just a work around that will not help you with the next similar problem (overload resolution when using a function in a template)

Comment: yeah, i forgot about the error, sorry

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `ostream_iterator<char>` instead of `ostream_iterator<string>`:

```
transform(s.begin(),s.end(),ostream_iterator<char>(cout,"\n"),std::toupper);
```

`std::transform` transforms each character and pass it to the output iterator. That is why the type argument of the output iterator should be `char` instead of `std::string`.

By the way, each character will be printed on a newline. Is that what you want? If not, don't pass `"\n"`.

--

**Note :** You may have to use `::toupper` instead of `std::toupper`.

See these

- http://www.ideone.com/x6FB5  (each character on a newline)
- http://www.ideone.com/RcEKn   (all characters on the same line)

Comment: I see what you mean, but I get the same error with char to :-/

Comment: error: no matching function for call to 'transform(std::basic_string<char>::iterator, std::basic_string<char>::iterator, std::ostream_iterator<char>, <unresolved overloaded function type>)'

Comment: @vBx: You may have to use `::toupper` instead of `std::toupper`. See the edit and the demo.

Comment: Be aware that it's undefined behavior to pass a negative number to `::toupper`.

Comment: @vBx Or seems to.  It's undefined behavior (although some implementations go out of their way to make it work, most of the time).  As a test string, you might want to try `"L'Haÿ"` (the name of a suburb of Paris); this should result in `"L'HAŸ"`, but probably won't if plain `char` is signed (the default on most systems).

Comment: [Don't use `::toupper`.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131858/stdtransform-and-toupper-no-matching-function/7132065#7132065)

Answer (score 4):

First, if you want to output `char`s (and all of the `char`s), you'll
need to use `ostreambuf_iterator<char>`, and not
`ostream_iterator<string>`.  And `ostreambuf_iterator<char>` expresses
better what you want than `ostream_iterator<char>`; you're
outputting `char`s directly, not formatting anything.
(`ostream_iterator` uses the `<<` operator, which formats.)

Second, be aware that there is not always a one to one translation of
lower to upper (e.g. `'ß'` maps to the two character sequence `"SS"` in
upper case), so `std::transform` can't really be used to do the job
correctly.  (And of course, it doesn't handle multibyte encodings like
UTF-8 correctly.)  For all but the simplest uses, you need something
more complicated.  But even for the simplest cases:

`std::toupper` is overloaded: one of the overloads is a template, which
takes two arguments, and the other is a function which takes a single
`int`; neither will work directly here, and the fact that `transform` is
also a template means that overload resolution and template type
deduction won't work even if they did.  So basically, you have to add
something.  It's possible to use the 2 argument template function if you
add enough qualifiers and use `boost::bind` or something similar to bind
the second argument, but it's almost as much text as writing a simple
`toupper` functional argument your self.  And you can't use the single
argument form (which can be unambiguously accessed if you include
`<ctype.h>` and use `::toupper`) because it has undefined behavior if
you use a `char` as the argument when you call it: you have to convert
the `char` to `unsigned char` first (unless, of course, plain `char` is
unsigned in the implementation you are using—and in all
implementations to which your code will ever be ported).

Comment: +1, This does actually tackle the issue in the question, rather than blindly proposing changes. For a simple solution that uses the `int toupper(int)` you only need a cast in the last argument: `std::transform( ..., (int (*)(int)) std::toupper );`, as that will resolve the overload: only one of the `toupper` overloads can be casted to that particular function signature.

Comment: @David The problem is that using `int toupper(int)` results in undefined behavior; you don't want to use it directly.