# std::transform() and toupper(), no matching function

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

I tried the code from this question [C++ std::transform() and toupper() ..why does this fail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489313/c-stdtransform-and-toupper-why-does-this-fail)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
  std::string s="hello";
  std::string out;
  std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), std::back_inserter(out), std::toupper);
  std::cout << "hello in upper case: " << out << std::endl;
}
```

Theoretically it should've worked as it's one of the examples in Josuttis' book, but it doesn't compile http://ideone.com/aYnfv.

Why did GCC complain:

```
no matching function for call to ‘transform(
    __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string
        <char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, 
    __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string
        <char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, 
    std::back_insert_iterator<std::basic_string
        <char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >,
    <unresolved overloaded function type>)’
```

Am I missing something here? Is it GCC related problem?

Comment: The one in the `std` namespace does not match the function prototype. So it complains.

Comment: @CodeMonkey: There is more than one. So it complains.

Comment: @Tomalak: Yes, same difference.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Just use `::toupper` instead of `std::toupper`. That is, `toupper` defined in the global namespace, instead of the one defined in `std` namespace.

```
std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), std::back_inserter(out), ::toupper);
```

Its working : http://ideone.com/XURh7

Reason why your code is not working :  there is another overloaded function `toupper` in the namespace `std` which is causing problem when resolving the name, because compiler is unable to decide which overload you're referring to, when you simply pass `std::toupper`. That is why the compiler is saying `unresolved overloaded function type` in the error message, which indicates the presence of overload(s).

So to help the compiler in resolving to the correct overload, you've to cast `std::toupper` as

```
(int (*)(int))std::toupper
```

That is, the following would work:

```
//see the last argument, how it is casted to appropriate type
std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), std::back_inserter(out),(int (*)(int))std::toupper);
```

Check it out yourself: http://ideone.com/8A6iV

Comment: This indeed works, but why?  `toupper` is also in the `std` namespace (via `<cctype>`).

Comment: @Oli: As I said, there is another overload which is causing the problem. Also, `toupper` also exists in the global namespace (atleast in GCC version).

Comment: @Nawaz: This doesn't sound like an overload ambiguity (`std::toupper` and `::toupper` are completely distinct).  It just sounds like the prototypes differ.

Comment: @Tomalak: The error does say `unresolved overloaded function type` which implies there is an overload.

Comment: @Nawaz: Oh, I missed that. You're absolutely right. However, I believe your answer's reasoning is wrong; `::toupper` is not conflicting with `std::toupper`; rather, `::toupper` doesn't have any overloads of itself to conflict with, whereas `std::toupper` does.

Comment: @Tomalak: That is what I said *"..overloaded function toupper in the namespace std"* which means `std::toupper` has overload.

Comment: @Nawaz: What overloads are there?  In GCC 4.1.2, `<cctype>` simply has `namespace std { ... using ::toupper; }`.

Comment: @Oli: `<locale>` defines `template <class charT> charT toupper(charT c, const locale& loc)`

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: There's an [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fk4ystc%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) that takes a locale.

Comment: If you do use `::toupper`, it would be best to include the C header (`<ctype.h>`) to make sure it's in the global namespace. Then you'll be relying on deprecated but well-specified behaviour, not unspecified behaviour.

Comment: Sorry, but the opening to this answer ("Just use toupper instead of std::toupper") is incomplete. If the OP uses `using namespace std` then [it ceases to be a viable workaround](http://ideone.com/GiJw2) (not to mention that you're either using deprecated or unspecified behaviour even when it _does_ work).

Comment: @Tomalak: That is true, but 1) I never said `Just use toupper instead of `std::toupper` is a complete answer, and that is why I added the explanation and what to do with `std::toupper` to make it work. 2) If you read the post incompletely, you will get an incomplete answer. 3) Also, the bigger problem is in `using namespace std` than in `toupper`. How many of us recommend this in the first place? 4) I've already seen him using `std::transform` and `std::toupper` - the fully qualified names, I can assume that he wouldn't add `using namespace std`.[contd.]

Comment: @Tomalak: [contd]. 5) But to make you happy, I'm going to add `::` to `toupper`. :-)

Comment: @Nawaz: Better. :) I think it was misleading before; there was no indication at all that the latter workaround was superior to the former. And assuming that he'll _never_ have `std::toupper` in scope is a bit of a leap, and makes for a non-robust answer. :)

Comment: I think it's the use of the word "just" that implies excess simplicity, and that the sentence may be taken on its own without the rest of the answer. "Just" means that there are no further caveats.

Answer (score 52):

#### Problem

```
std::transform(
    s.begin(),
    s.end(),
    std::back_inserter(out),
    std::toupper
);
```

> no matching function for call to ‘`transform(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::back_insert_iterator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, <unresolved overloaded function type>)`’

This is a misleading error; the interesting part is not that there's "no matching function" for the call, but *why* there's no matching function.

The *why* is that you're passing a function reference of an "`<unresolved overloaded function type>`" as an argument, and GCC prefers to error on the call rather than on this overload resolution failure.

---

#### Explanation

First, you should consider how the C library is inherited in C++. `<ctype.h>` has a function `int toupper(int)`.

C++ inherits this:

> `[n3290: 21.7/1]:` Tables 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, and 79 describe headers
>   `<cctype>`, `<cwctype>`, `<cstring>`, `<cwchar>`, `<cstdlib>`
>   (character conversions), and `<cuchar>`, respectively.
>
> `[n3290: 21.7/2]:` The contents of these headers shall be the same as
>   the Standard C Library headers `<ctype.h>`, `<wctype.h>`,
>   `<string.h>`, `<wchar.h>`, and `<stdlib.h>` and the C Unicode TR
>   header `<uchar.h>`, respectively [..]
>
> `[n3290: 17.6.1.2/6]:`Names that are defined as functions in C shall
>   be defined as functions in the C++ standard library.

But using `<ctype.h>` is deprecated:

> `[n3290: C.3.1/1]:` For compatibility with the Standard C library, the
>   C++ standard library provides the 18 C headers (D.5), but their use is
>   deprecated in C++.

And the way to access the C `toupper` is through the C++ backwards-compatibility header `<cctype>`. For such headers, the contents are *either moved or copied* (depending on your implementation) into the `std` namespace:

> `[n3290: 17.6.1.2/4]:` [..] In the C++ standard library, however, the declarations
>   (except for names which are defined as macros in C) are within
>   namespace scope (3.3.6) of the namespace std. **It is unspecified
>   whether these names are first declared within the global namespace
>   scope and are then injected into namespace std by explicit
>   using-declarations** (7.3.3).

But the C++ library also introduces a new, locale-specific function template in header `<locale>`, that's *also* called `toupper` (of course, in namespace `std`):

> `[n3290: 22.2]:` [..] `template <class charT> charT toupper(charT c,
>   const locale& loc);` [..]

So, when you use `std::toupper`, there are *two* overloads to choose from. Since you didn't tell GCC which function you wish to use, the overload cannot be resolved and your call to `std::transform` cannot be completed.

---

#### Disparity

Now, the OP of that original question did not run into this problem. He likely did not have the locale version of `std::toupper` in scope, but then again you didn't `#include <locale>` either!

However:

> `[n3290: 17.6.5.2]:` A C++ header may include other C++ headers.

So it *just so happens* that either your `<iostream>` or your `<algorithm>`, or headers that those headers include, or headers that *those* headers include (etc), lead to the inclusion of `<locale>` on your implementation.

---

#### Solution

There are two workarounds to this.

1. You may provide a conversion clause to coerce the function pointer into referring to the overload that you wish to use:

   ```
   std::transform(
      s.begin(),
      s.end(),
      std::back_inserter(out),
      (int (*)(int))std::toupper  // specific overload requested
   );
   ```
2. You may remove the locale version from the overload set by explicitly using the global `toupper`:

   ```
   std::transform(
      s.begin(),
      s.end(),
      std::back_inserter(out),
      ::toupper                  // global scope
   );
   ```

   However, recall that whether or not this function in `<cctype>` is available is unspecified (`[17.6.1.2/4]`), and using `<ctype.h>` is deprecated (`[C.3.1/1]`).

   Thus, this is not the option that I would recommend.

---

<sup>(**Note:** I despise writing angle brackets as if they were part of header names — they are part of `#include` syntax, not header names — but I've done it here for consistency with the FDIS quotes; and, to be honest, it *is* clearer...)</sup>

Comment: **Note:** This is all slightly silly, because `std::transform` is, itself, looking for a specific function signature so in theory the compiler could deduce solution 1 _for you_. But, well, it's complicated; and welcome to C++.

Comment: Great exposition man, I need some time to understand many of the points mentioned. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Stack: No problem! It took me some time to collate them. :P

Comment: a bit late to the party, but I still think the compiler should AT LEAST list the ambigous options.

Comment: @Vargas: It can't! The options don't exist (or there are infinite options, depending on how you look at it) until `std::transform` (a template) has been instantiated, which cannot happen until the type of the final argument (the functor) is known. Chicken vs egg :)

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet Interestingly, it seems that Visual C++ _is_ able to deduce solution 1 for you, at least in my experience.  I was attempting to troubleshoot a runtime error in a different environment, so I copied the relevant part of the project into an online Linux GCC compiler, and it wouldn't even compile because GCC couldn't resolve the overload.  The code compiles with both Visual Studio 2010 and VS2015 WebCompiler, but not with GCC.  This suggests to me that the <locale> overloads are only visible in MSVC if you explicitly include the header, while they're always visible in GCC.

Comment: That, or MSVC is just better at deducing the right one, but I'm not sure if the way it does so is standard-compliant.

Comment: @JustinTime: Don't forget that standard headers are allowed to include other standard headers and it's unspecified which (if any) those will be, under any given implementation.

Comment: True, forgot about that.  It's possible that GCC includes `<locale>` behind the scenes when you include `<cctype>` and/or `<algorithm>`, and VS doesn't.  Alternatively, it's possible that one of the other headers (most likely `<string>`) includes `<locale>` behind the scenes.

Comment: ...And it seems that's the issue, or at least a significant part of it.  To determine if this was the reason for the difference in behaviour, I wrote a simple program that reads a string, transforms it with `toupper()`, & outputs the result.  It includes `<iostream>`, `<string>`, `<cctype>`, `<locale>`, & `<algorithm>`.  It seems that, interestingly enough, MSVC 2010 is able to correctly deduce which version of `toupper()` you want, while later versions (or at least 2015) can't.  MSVC 2015 is fine as long as you don't explicitly include `<locale>`, but it can't resolve the overload if you do.

Comment: This suggests that MSVC 2010 is exhibiting abnormal behaviour, while GCC and MSVC 2015 are more in line with what one would expect.  It also suggests that GCC includes `<locale>` behind the scenes, while MSVC does not.  Guess that answers that, then.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), 
std::bind(&std::toupper<char>, std::placeholders::_1, std::locale()));
```

If you use vc toolchain,please include locale