# C++ best practice to identify whether a digit is in a certain range

Tags: c++

Which way is better to identify a digit? I'm analyzing a 9 digit array of integers to test whether they are all between `0-9` inclusive.

```
for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    if (str[i] < 48 || str[i] > 57) {
        cout >> "failed" >> endl;
    }
    else {
        cout >> "passed" >> endl;
    }
}  


for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    if (str[i] < '0' || str[i] > '9') {
        cout >> "failed" >> endl;
    }
    else {
        cout >> "passed" >> endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: The latter one will work when ASCII isn't in use.

Comment: What do you mean when "ASCII isn't in use"?

Comment: ASCII is one character set and the most common one. In ASCII, '0' is 48 and 'A' is 65. It's not guaranteed to be in use, however, so in your code, 'A' could actually be 25, or whatever the character set in use defines it as. The [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) article might help a bit.

Comment: Besides portablility, which, realistically, isn't much of an issue in this case, the second is much more comprehensible, especially to someone who doesn't have the ASCII table memorized.  The first one should have a comment, the second is self-documenting.

Comment: Thanks guys, cleared it up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use [`isdigit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit).

Your second option also works. The first one [doesn't have to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13141776/is-the-character-set-of-a-char-literal-guaranteed-to-be-ascii), because `'0'` doesn't necessarily have to correspond to `48`. The values are guaranteed to be consecutive, but they don't have to start at `48` (although they likely do).

Comment: Could you elaborate on why '0' doesn't necessarily have to evaluate to 48? Should I use my first example instead of the second example?

Comment: @eveo check the link I provided. Also, I said that the second is better.

Answer (score 4):

I would use `std::all_of` in combination with a predicate (better if a short, terse lambda) that uses `std::isdigit()`:

```
bool ok = std::all_of(begin(str), end(str), [] (char c) { return std::isdigit(c); });
```

This allows you to test any sub-range you wish, and the iteration cycle comes for free.

You have to include the `<cctype>` header (for `std::isdigit()`) and the `<algorithm>` header (for `std::all_of`).

**EDIT:**

If you do not want to use a lambda, you can even pass in the `std::digit` function directly, if you provide a proper cast (see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131858/stdtransform-and-toupper-no-matching-function) for an explanation):

```
bool ok = std::all_of(begin(str), end(str), (int (*)(int))std::isdigit);
```

The cast is necessary because in the `std` namespace, there are overloads of `isdigit` which is causing problem in overload resolution. The [other topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131858/stdtransform-and-toupper-no-matching-function) discusses a similar case in a bit detail.

Or if that looks cumbersome, you can do this instead:

```
int (*predicate)(int) = std::isdigit;
bool ok = std::all_of(begin(str), end(str), predicate);
```

That should work fine!

Comment: @AndyProwl: Why even lambda? You can pass `std::isdigit` itself as third argument :  `std::all_of(begin(str), end(str), std::isdigit);`. Can't you?

Comment: That's a fantastic example but I'm afraid I can't use that as this is a basic C++ course designed to do things the hard way so you can understand the internals of the language.

Comment: @Nawaz: well, that's what I thought, then I tried it and it didn't work... so I thought I'd figure out why first

Comment: @eveo: I understand. In that case, I'd go for the second alternative you propose. The first one is not portable (see answer by @LuchianGrigore)

Comment: @AndyProwl: What is the error? You probably need to cast into the proper type. there may be overloads which create problem : See this : [std::transform() and toupper(), no matching function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131858/stdtransform-and-toupper-no-matching-function). The same probably is true of `std::digit` also?

Comment: @AndyProwl: Yes, it is exactly the [same problem](http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=4038c11671a5acbc1ab436db0af95452). Once it cast [it works great!](http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=5d4f6830ff5cc2015985e57aa1ab69f9)

Comment: Personally, I prefer the lambda.  The cast is ugly and syntactically error prone.

Comment: [Even this works without cast](http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=28cdf8273f0d0d443168e5dc7dd9507e), though not sure if the existence of `::isdigit` is guaranteed by the Standard.

Comment: @Nawaz: 17.6.1.1/2 says: "All library entities except macros, operator new and operator delete are defined within the namespace `std` or namespaces nested within namespace `std`". So I guess that's not portable